# Confusion about different confidence interval calculated

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, descriptive-statistics

I recently computed an independent t test (2-tailed test) question in Spss using the parameters below:

H0: There's no difference in the mean scores of a maths quiz taken by students in class A and B.

H1: There's a difference in the mean scores of a maths quiz taken by students in class A and B.

Class A: n = 70, mean = 4.3226, SD = 1.11731, SEM = 0.13354

Class B: n = 269, mean = 4.4117, SD = 1.14620, SEM = 0.06988

The 95% CI calculated was (-0.39006,0.21188)

However,when I swap the 2 groups around, the 95% CI becomes (-0.21188,0.39006).

While I understand that the range is the same, the values aren't, and there's an overlap between the 2 CIs. Which CI do I use?

Comment: You have to define a direction for your difference: for example, does your hypothesis say group 1 is better?

Comment: Sorry that I forgot to mention that, my hypothesis just wanted to find out if there's a difference between the 2 mean. (2-tailed test)

Comment: Okay, but define that difference. That tells you which confidence interval to use.

Comment: Is it alright if you can clarify what do you mean by the direction of the difference? As I was under the impression that I just wanted to find if there's any difference, hence I did a 2-tailed test instead of 1-tailed. I don't have to come up with the direction of group 1 is better or worse right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is one minus the other.  Which term comes first in a subtraction affects the sign of the difference though not the magnitude

Your first confidence interval of $(-0.39006,0.21188)$ is for the difference in the population means $\mu_A- \mu_B$

Your second confidence interval of $(-0.21188,0.39006)$ is for $\mu_B- \mu_A$ so is $-1$ times the first

Since $0$ is in the confidence interval (either), you presumably will not be rejecting the null hypothesis